# MakeFile to run Mocha tests with NPM

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, makefile, bdd, mocha.js

I am trying to create a MakeFile to run my Mocha unit tests with NPM. So I have Mocha installed and a unit test created in:

> {project_root}/test/test.js

Now, when I try 'make test' Make replies with:

> make: Nothing to be done for `test'.

Here's my MakeFile:

```
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u tdd
.PHONY: test
```

So real basic. I've read that Mocha will run all tests in the 'test' dir automatically. Is my MakeFile syntax incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: your command seems to be ok , but you could try this : `make -f MakeFile test` . Also i would put the .Phony line before the test target and check my makefile with the command cat -e -t -v MakeFile --> it shows tabs as ^I and line endings as $ . let me know if it still dosent work

Comment: Thanks. make -f did it. I will look up the meaning of that argument.

Comment: @ Nick , the -f command just says that the name after it is a file .... that it!!

Comment: @Nick This is old, but make expects a file called `makefile` or `Makefile`.  The uppercase F in `makeFile`/`MakeFile` is what trips this error.  Case matters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry I can't help with make syntax, but could I suggest instead to just create a test alias in your package.json so that you can run your tests with `npm test`. Here's a nice example: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/package.json

Comment: That's good advice. This would be supported by Windows as well as unix based systems. I'll take a look.

Comment: Yep... I like it. Ditched the MakeFile and just added "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  }, to my package.json. Works great. Less moving parts.

Comment: I want to have two test commands, eg: testThis, testThat. I don't want a makefile and npm doesn't support it what should i use?

Comment: @facebook see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376269/how-to-run-mocha-and-mocha-phantomjs-tests-from-one-npm-test-command-in-node-j/20384739#20384739 on how to create multiple test commands, then run with `npm run testThis`.

Comment: It's funny that the package.json from sequelize now just calls out to the Makefile :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try tabs instead of spaces?

```
test:
  @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
.PHONY: test
```

Greetings,

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is caused by an improperly named makefile.

Rename your makefile to `makefile` or `Makefile` and do not use a capital `F`.