# How to run mocha and mocha-phantomjs tests from one "npm test" command in node.js?

Tags: node.js, testing, browser, phantomjs, mocha.js

I have got few node packages which works in node.js environment and also in browser. Now I have got two seperate tests (for each environment). What is the best way to run these tests with just `npm test` command? Also I want to add these packages to travis.

I'm using `mocha` and `mocha-phantomjs`.

**Node test command**

```
node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./test/node/index.js --reporter spec
```

**Browser test command**

```
node ./node_modules/mocha-phantomjs/bin/mocha-phantomjs ./test/browser/index.html
```

**What I tried:**

1. Add these commands into `npm test` script seperated with semicolon

   - *Problem:* When there is an error in first script but no error in second script, command exited with 0 and travis build passed.
2. Let node command test in `npm test` script and create custom script for browser tests. Than add these two commands (`npm test` and `npm run-script test-browser`) into travis.yml as array.

   - *Problem:* Users have to run manually two independent test scripts.
3. Let node command test in `npm test` script and add browser tests to `npm posttest` command. Travis.yml will than have got just one script and users will also have to run one script (everyone is happy).

   - *Problem:* It just does't feel right, so I wanted to know if there is some better way.

Comment: How about solution 1 but with `&&` instead of a semicolon? In this way if the first command fails, the second command isn't executed and the whole command fails; if the first passes and the second fails, the whole command still fails.

Comment: Ou.. You are right and I completely forgot that option, so I will add it as the right answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I like the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test-node && npm run test-browser",
    "test-node": "mocha -R spec ./test/node/index.js",
    "test-browser": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/browser/index.html"}
```

The `&&` only runs the second if the first passes, and you can run either separately if you want. Note that npm always uses the [relative mocha](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) (inside node_modules), not the global one, so there's no harm in just calling `mocha` and `mocha-phantomjs` directly. You can be even more efficient with mocha's `-b` option for bail, which will quit as soon as it encounters an error.

Comment: Great, I must say, that I really like this. I also was not sure if node will use the relative modules in first place even from command line and I was too bored to try it. So really thank you for both your suggestions.

Comment: Thankyou so much for this, have been stuck for a while!

Comment: Just a note here, I believe that this is going to try and run the first and if that fails with an exit code, then it will never run the second. I don't know if this is a good thing or bad :/

Comment: Hi, great solution! I'm trying to adapt it a server-side test though and I'm having trouble bootstrapping my server and then running all the tests on it. Right now the best I can do is start/stop the server with each test file. Is there some way to start it once and run all the tests on it? I know this is almost an entirely separate issue but just figured I'd try :)

Comment: @ThomasReggi - replace the "&&" with a ";" if you want the 2nd test to run regardless of the success of the first.    A note  : To run all the tests you use `npm test`, to run just the 'test-node' one you use `npm test test-node`.   Great answer - thank you - I am brand new to mocha and was struggling getting multiple tests organised.

Comment: Hmm... I was wrong, `npm test test-node` does not run that one test.  What command is used to run a single test?

Answer (score 4):

Came here looking for information on configuring `npm` with `karma`. [@dankohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384739/24874) can be adapted thusly:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run test-node && npm run test-browser",
  "test-node": "karma run",
  "test-browser": "karma start --single-run"
}
```

Hope this helps someone else out.

Comment: are you sure that `karma run` does what you say? that command says to me `There is no server listening on port 9876`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `npm-run-all` package:

`npm install npm-run-all --save-dev`

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm-run-all test-mocha test-mocha-phantomjs",
  "test-mocha": "mocha ./test/node/index.js --reporter spec",
  "test-mocha-phantomjs": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/browser/index.html"
}
```

It will run local copies of `mocha` and `mocha-phantomjs`. Twitter bootstrap uses this library for development.